# Differences between "Ishwar" and "Bhagvan"?

Tags: terminology

We Hindus often hear the words "ishwar" and "bhagvan" . What are the differences between these two words?

Comment: Short version of [jabahar's](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/682/267) answer with an analogy: There is no difference, the same way there is no difference between `two` and `2` -- they both refer to the same entity.

Comment: yes there is literally no difference between Bhagavan and the Isvara!!

Comment: As I am Muslim, don't say about anybody's belief but as per my wide understanding on various religion I mean that, ISHWAR has create and nominate BHAGAWAN on earth.
So that BHAGAWAN has parents, but ISHWAR has not. BHAGAWAN has wife and child, but ISHWAR has not. BHAGAWAN has life & death, but ISHWAR alive forever. ISHWAR is not only for mankind but for all live and dead. He is an owner not only for earth but for whole universe.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*Bhagvan* is a term made of two different words, *bhaga* and *van*. *Bhaga* generally means supreme opulence. The Vishnu Purana defines *bhaga* as below:

> *aiśvaryasya samagrasya dharmasya yaśasariśrayaḥ
>
>   jñānavairāgyayoścaiva ṣaṇṇāṃ bhaga itīraṇā* [VP - 6.5.74]
>
> **Meaning**
>   Complete splendor, virtue, glory, opulence, knowledge, dispassion - these six are known as *bhaga*.

So just like one who has *dhana* (wealth) is known as *dhanavan*, one how has all these six is known as *bhagavan*. ( *bhaga* + *van* = *bhagavan* ) But the opluences descried above are only found in the supreme personality of Godhead. Hence, the absolute truth, Brahman is also called as *Bhagavan*.

Apart from this, Bhagavan also means the omniscient being who has the complete knowledge of creation, dissolution, knowledge, ignorance, etc.:

> *utpattiṃ pralayaṃ caiva bhūtānāmāgatiṃ gatim
>
>   vettiṃ vidyāmavidyāṃ ca sa vācyo bhagavāniti* [VP - 6.5.78]

Now, regarding *Ishwara*, it has been **derived from the Sanskrit root *ish***, which means to rule. So *Ishwara* means the supreme being who rules over everyone and everything. But as God is  only such being, He is also known as *Ishwara*. ( ***īśate iti īśvaraḥ*** )

So **irrespective of whether we say *Bhagavan* or *Iswara*, both imply the same personal form of God**. Just their meanings are different.

Comment: sir. What is the difference between opulance and splendor . If possible can you give hindi/sanskrit/telugu equalent words for my understanding..

Answer (score 5):

In Hindu Religion, the word Bhagwan has symbolic meaning too. The word encompasses Earth, Water, Fire, Air and Space – the five elements. Thus the term Bhagavan translates as the manifestation of the physical form of universe.

In the word भगवान (Bhagavan) –

‘भ’ stands for Bhoomi or Earth

'ग' stands for Gagan or Space

‘व’ stands for Vayu or Air

‘आ’ stands for Agni or Fire

‘न’ stands for Neer or Water

Comment: Good! But the question is "What is the difference between “Ishwar” and “Bhagvan”?

Comment: @hims056 since there is apparently no difference so it made sense to just detail the meaning of *Bhagwan* rather have a separate ques. for same.

Comment: @vedicd You could have mentioned that there is no difference in your answer itself. It would have given a better answer.

Comment: This answer seems constructed

Comment: @Partha what do you mean?