# What is the difference between ISHWAR AND BHAGWAN?

Tags: terminology

I want to know what is difference between ishwar & bhagwan?

Comment: Ishwara is the one who is the Master or Lord of all, i.e. God. Bhagavan simply means God i think. So Bhagavan is Ishwara and Ishwara is Bhagavan. God is the Lord and Lord is the God. All the best.

Answer (score 2):

```
may be  following link help full for  your questions
```

[difference between ISHWAR AND BHAGWAN?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/678/differences-between-ishwar-and-bhagvan)